# Remove array from array inside get_option

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm using the WordPress `get_option()` to get my database option of an array of users.

So I have the following method:

```
    public function deauthorize_instagram_via_button()
    {
        if (!get_option('instagram_authenticated_users')) {
            return;
        }
        $users = get_option('instagram_authenticated_users');
        
        // If we have single entry, delete the option from the database
        if (count($users) === 1) {
            delete_option('instagram_authenticated_users');
            $this->instagram->delete_cache();
        }

        // This returns the user_id
        var_dump($_POST['user_id']);
        die();

        // delete_option('instagram_authenticated_users');
        exit;
    }
```

Where `get_option('instagram_authenticated_users')` returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(9) "sem_test1"
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(17841400835712753)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(12) "sem_test2"
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(17841449642220098)
  }
}
```

Then I have a `$_POST['user_id']` which returns `user_id => 17841449642220098`.

How can I search through the array and remove that `user_id`'s array and then call `update_option('instagram_authenticated_users')` so that I keep just one single array inside the array.

So after it gets remove, the `get_option('instagram_authenticated_users')` will look like this when called:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(9) "sem_test1"
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(17841400835712753)
  }
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` like below:

```
// get current list
$users = get_option('instagram_authenticated_users');

// filter out POST user id
$filtered_users = array_filter($users, function($user){
    return $user["user_id"] !== (int) $_POST['user_id'];
});

// save filtered array
update_option('instagram_authenticated_users', $filtered_users);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just tried this and for some odd reason, it's still returning two indexes of arrays inside $filtered_users via the debugger, could it be that update_option is never touched because the return inside filtered_users returns the method early?

Comment: Updated my answer.  I think the issue is that the post id is a string and the array id is an int.  In my update im casting the string id to an int.  Let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Nice, happy to help!